# jquery attached element disappears unintended after clicking

Tags: jquery, html, append

As a jQuery newbie, I'm stumbling upon the following problem:

I have a button that appends a fieldset to an existing form. Works fine. Each fieldset furthermore has a button that ultimately is intended to delete that exact field again. For testing purposes, I bound a simple console.log to clicking on any of those delete buttons.

When I click on one of the delete buttons, the text is logged in the console. However, it only flashes for an instant before all previously appended fieldsets disappear completely from the document.

Here's the html

```
<form id="theform" class="form-inline">
    <fieldset class="aField" id="field1">
        <select id="products">
          <option>Item 1</option>
          <option>Item 2</option>
          <option>Item 3</option>
        </select>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" class="amount">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Price">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<button id="addtoform" class="btn test">New Product</button>
```

and here's the js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#addtoform').click(function() {
    var fields = $('.aField').length;
    var newField  = 'field' + String(fields + 1);
    var button = "<button class='btn btn-danger delete'>delete</button>";
    var newElem = $('#field1').clone().attr('id', newField).append(button); 

    $('#theform').append(newElem);
});

$("#theform").on("click", '.btn.btn-danger.delete', function () {
    console.log('ok, let me delete this.');
});
```

});

What is happening?

Comment: Check the code you posted. I can't see #addtoform in HTML. Prefer using jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the button. It's there now.

Comment: do a better log... like console.log("deleting:"+this.id) ... my quick guess is your problem is with the id's -- do you really need to have id's at all for the fieldsets?

Comment: for clarity, look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp ... "Tip: Always specify the type attribute for the <button> element. Different browsers may use different default types for the <button> element." ... i.e.- you want <button type='button'>...

Comment: Thank you @dlo, I find this a useful remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: you will it working and you can delete rest of the controls from the form.

```
$("#theform").on("click", '.btn.btn-danger.delete', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove(); // Delete appended element
    console.log('Element Deleted..');
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/EeqUJ/2/)

Comment: Ok, this does the job. If you have the nerve, would you mind explaining what the default is that is being prevented?

Comment: Sure! In case `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default behavior of control, [See API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: depending on your full page, the button could submit the form? which if it's back to self, could look like a deletion when it's really a refresh?

Comment: For example: If you remove `e.preventDefault()` from my code in fiddle you will see the behavior, that's why i wrote such thing there :)

Comment: Ok I get it, ok I see.

Answer (score 0):

This `$("#theform .btn.btn-danger.delete')` selects all buttons. You have to single out the button you want to delete.

Or even easier is:

```
$(".btn.btn-danger.delete").click(function(){
     $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

If your delete button is a child of your fieldset, this should remove only the parent fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

Is the statically declared fieldset being deleted too ?